# Description is not showing in plugin page

Tags: plugins

I've just uploaded my plugin in `WordPress repository`, everything is ok, the only thing is that Description is not showing in the plugin page

I've checked `readme.txt` file and main .php file but everything seems to be ok.

The plugin page is [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smartlink-dinamic-urls/), and it's been created a couple days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just with one paragraph:

> With SmartLink DU you can insert up to 5 URLs to a single link. Every
>   time the page is loaded, one of the 5 URLs you’ve entered will be
>   inserted in the link randomly.

The only "weird" thing that I saw was that you have multiple paragraphs and they were all together, if you put only one paragraph and it works you can try to add a line break between them.

It's a pretty buggy think, you could report it on: `plugins@wordpress.org`

Comment: ok. i'll try that.

I've already send mail.  still waiting for response

Comment: Nice, let me know, I'd like to know how this is handled.

Comment: It's solved..
A guy called Samuel Wood (Otto) replied mi mail, this is what he said

"Our system is very picky about formatting. You need to follow the example files precisely.

I removed all the excessive spacing in your readme.txt. That fixed it."

Now I'm a little bit scared to make any change ,,lol

Comment: Great! Nice to know it was the excessive spacing.